# past simple for a habit still in work

Tags: past-tense, past-simple

The train **_ at 8.30 p.m. today, but as a rule it _** at 8.00 p.m. sharp.

ANSWER: left and started

but could left and starts be ok as it is a general habits still in work at the time of writing  so present tense should be ok for start

no more context

Comment: That "ANSWER" is just plain "**WRONG!**" The second verb form should be Present Simple ***starts*** (where the verb subject is 3rd person singular ***it = the train***). Unless you're in a very unusual "past tense narrative" context (which is unlikely because adverbial ***today*** here), the implication is that "as a rule" still applies at time of speaking (i.e. - the train will probably leave at 8:00 as usual again tomorrow and subsequently; we're not talking about a timetable that used to be operated at some time in the past).

Comment: That 's what I thought

Comment: It's possible to imagine a "past tense narrative" context where ***started*** would be appropriate, but I'm sure most competent writers would use ***that day*** rather than ***today*** in that case. My advice to you would be *not* to use these ill-thought-out tests as an aid to learning English - particularly if, as I suspect might be the case here, the test was set by a non-native Anglophone in the first place. But even native speakers will often come up with poor quality examples like this (because they can't think of all *possible* contexts and/or interpretations for a given utterance).

Comment: ***Started*** is completely wrong, as mentioned. Strict grammar aside (which would make it ***starts***), if you want to use a parallel structure, it should be the same verb as used at the start of the sentence: ***leaves***.